# Rails3/Devise: undefined method new_application_user_session_path

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ldap, devise

Following the README documentation, I installed Devise into an existing Rails 3 application. However, it doesn't seem to work. When I try to access one of my controllers that have `before_filter :authenticate_application_user!`, I get the following error message:

```
undefined method 'new_application_user_session_path' for #<Devise::FailureApp::0x60aldc0>
```

I have no idea why. I've checked numerous to see if I followed the installation  guide correctly, to no avail. So I'm wondering if anyone cold help me out.

Here is my `routes.rb`

```
AwesomeApp::Application.routes.draw do

  devise_for :application_users

  root :to => "home#index"  

  scope "admin" do
    resources :application_users, :path => "users"    
  end
end
```

Here is my `Gemfile`:

```
source 'http://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.0.0'

gem 'ruby-oci8'
gem 'activerecord-oracle_enhanced-adapter'
gem 'warbler'

gem 'devise', '1.1.3'

group :development, :test do
  gem 'factory_girl_rails'
  gem 'forgery'
end
```

Here is my migration file for updating my existing database schema:

```
class DeviseCreateApplicationUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    change_table(:application_users) do |t|
      t.rememberable
      t.trackable
    end

  end

  def self.down
    change_table(:application_users) do |t|
      t.remove :rememberable, :trackable
    end
  end
end
```

**NOTE:** In case anyone is wondering, I will be authenticating using LDAP. So that's why you don't see `t.database_authenticatable`

Here is my model `application_user.rb`:

```
class ApplicationUser < AbstractModel

  devise :rememberable, :trackable, :timeoutable  

end
```

Here is my `devise.rb` initializer file:

```
Devise.setup do |config|
  config.mailer_sender = "please-change-me@config-initializers-devise.com"
  require 'devise/orm/active_record'
  config.authentication_keys = [ :user_ldap_id ]
  config.stretches = 10
  config.encryptor = :bcrypt
  config.pepper = "SALT AND PEPPERS HERE, SALT SALT SALT"
end
```

**NOTE:** Because I will be authenticating against LDAP, I am using a different column other than  the default `email` column that Devise defaults to. As a result, I had to install the Devise views (`rails g devise:views`) and modify the `app/views/devise/session/new.html.erb` file to use `user_ldap_id` instead of `email`.

**NOTE:** I removed any irrelevant code from these snippets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was because I did not have the `database_authenticable` enabled in my model. Without that, no routes will be generated. But because I don't need it, there was no point. However, to resolve this issue, I had to install Devise LDAP Authenticatable and enabled it in my model. Once I did that and restarted the server, the route became accessible.

Take a look at this ticket I created on the Devise Github repo. Someone there was able to walk me through the entire thing. Quite impressed actually at how responsive they were.

https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/issues/issue/614/#comment_517418

Added the following to my Gemfile:

```
gem 'devise_ldap_authenticatable'
```

Added the following to my application_users.rb:

```
devise :ldap_authenticatable
```